# How can I show JavaFX Charts in e4 SWT?

Tags: eclipse, javafx, e4

How can I show JavaFX Charts in e4 ?

For example this.

```
 Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Imported Fruits");
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new PieChart.Data("Grapefruit", 13),
                new PieChart.Data("Oranges", 25),
                new PieChart.Data("Plums", 10),
                new PieChart.Data("Pears", 22),
                new PieChart.Data("Apples", 30));
        final PieChart chart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
        chart.setTitle("Imported Fruits");

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(chart);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
```

Anything I can `Inject` here ?

**UPDATED**

Code

```
@PostConstruct
    public void initializeChart(Composite parent) {
        FXCanvas canvas = new FXCanvas(parent, SWT.NONE);
        Group group = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(group);
        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections
                .observableArrayList(new PieChart.Data("Grapefruit", 13),
                        new PieChart.Data("Oranges", 25), new PieChart.Data(
                                "Plums", 10), new PieChart.Data("Pears", 22),
                        new PieChart.Data("Apples", 30));
        final PieChart chart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
        chart.setTitle("Imported Fruits");
        group.getChildren().add(chart);
        canvas.setScene(scene);
    }
```

I launch my appication with jdk 1.8.0_45 and yet I get the following error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/Parent
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:306)
    ... 124 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.Parent cannot be found by amap.impactassessment_1.0.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 128 more
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you using SWT for e4 or are you using e(fx)clipse (where everything is JavaFX)?

Comment: I believe you use [FXCanvas](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swt/FXCanvas.html) to include JavaFX in SWT

Comment: Seems like I must use JDK 1.8.0_40. I am trying this out. Thanks

Comment: Any idea why I cant find `FXCanvas` in JDK 1.8.0_45 ?

Comment: Probably something to do with the jfxswt.jar libraries not being included in the JRE system libraries by Eclipse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question has turned into a duplicate of this question
[e(fx)clipse equinox compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485270/efxclipse-equinox-compilation-error) but since some things have changed since then, I will answer here.

To start I quote Tom Schindl answering the original question:

> The reason you see the "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" is that Equinox does not consult the Ext-classpath and most likely you don't tell Equinox to use our adaptor hooks who make equinox consult that path.
>
> What you need to do is to:
>
> Ensure that you have `org.eclipse.fx.osgi` fragment in your launch and make
>   sure you pass `-Dosgi.framework.extensions=org.eclipse.fx.osgi` as VM
>   arguments in your launch config

Using this method, you will also have to import the `javafx.*` packages in your `MANIFEST.MF` and you will need to have the bundle `org.eclipse.fx.javafx` in your target platform to provide these imports.

An alternative, easier way to go is to tell Equinox to use the extension class loader by adding

```
-Dorg.osgi.framework.bundle.parent=ext
```

to the vm arguments. Using this, you **don't** need the bundles `org.eclipse.fx.osgi` and `org.eclipse.fx.javafx` anymore and you don't need to modify the `MANIFEST.MF`.

This style has recently been advised by Tom Schindl and is also used by e(fx)clipse with version 2.0. See this forum post for more information: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1063826/